# Como obter as conversões por meta

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Trabalhando com API para manipular os dados sobre [conversão](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=goal_conversions), consigo obter o total das conversões por meta caso eu deixe explicito o parâmetro de consulta da API para métrica, da seguinte forma:

```
    $metrics    = 'ga:goal1Completions,ga:goal2Completions,ga:goal3Completions',
   [
        'dimensions'    => 'ga:date',
        'output'        => 'dataTable'
    ]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema de efetuar nessa forma é que eu não sei quantas metas estão cadastradas para cada cliente, isso varia entre 1 e 20. É inviável listar de 1 a 20, e caso retorne `0` eu tratar a linha, que é o caso da meta 3 no exemplo, que não existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso chamar o método [`listManagementGoals`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list) da API do Analytics.

```
/**
 * Example #1:
 * Requests goals for a single view (profile).
 */
try {
  $goals = $analytics->management_goals->listManagementGoals('123456',
      'UA-123456-1',
      '7654321');

} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

} catch (apiException $e) {
  print 'There was a general API error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Baseado na resposta do [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3791516/matt) no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36068698/1432957).